# How do you resolve egg_info error when installing feature_selector in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, installation, package, feature-selection

I am using Anaconda:  Jupyter Notebook. I am trying to install feature_selector. At first, I ran:
**from feature_selector import FeatureSelector**. However, it says "No module named feature_selector", so I ran      **pip install feature_selector**, but it does not successfully install. I get the following large error:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: ============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [2.1.2]
                python: yes [3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC
                        v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]]
              platform: yes [win32]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.16.4]
                   six: yes [using six version 1.12.0]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.8.0]
backports.functools_lru_cache: yes [Not required]
          subprocess32: yes [Not required]
                  pytz: yes [using pytz version 2019.1]
                cycler: yes [using cycler version 0.10.0]
               tornado: yes [using tornado version 6.0.3]
             pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.4.0]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype
                        (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be found.  You may
                        need to install the development package.]
                   png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
        toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: yes [installing, Qt: 5.9.6, PyQt: 5.9.6; PySide2 not
                        found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                        Tk]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: yes [installing]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: no
                 latex: no
               pdftops: no

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype, png * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourc
                        * eforge.net/packages/freetype.htm for instructions
                        * to install freetype * Please check http://gnuwin32
                        * .sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm for
                        * instructions to install png
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
```

**Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/feature-selector/issues/9

This should get you installed on any platform:

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/feature-selector.git>  
> cd feature-selector>   
> pip install -e .
> ```

Comment: I think you meant to use both a code block and a quote. Because "https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/feature-selector.git>" gets me "Not found"